# EWS Managed API - Save Draft with inline Images

Tags: c#, html-email, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to create emails for my users using EWS Managed API 1.1, and need to use email templates our designers have created. I was able to successfully attach image (*say header.png*) and add an image tag like this (*using cid: before the image name*) in the html body.

```xml
<img width=683 height=27 src="cid:header.png" alt="Header">
```

This works when I use `msg.SendAndSaveCopy()` method. It renders perfectly fine in both Sent Mail folder and the recipients inbox. However it is not working when I try to use `msg.Save()` method just to save it as Draft in Drafts folder. It shows images as plain attachments and the body doesn't show images inline. They don't render properly even if I hit send in outlook. I am wondering if I need to do anything special to have these images rendered correctly in outlook Drafts folder.

Any pointers/ help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft provided a workaround today to address this issue. Posting the solution for the benefit of the community

```
      string html = @"<html>
                 <head>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                    <img width=200 height=100  id=""1"" src=""cid:Desert.jpg"">
                 </body>
                 </html>";

        newMessage.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, html);
        string file = @"D:\Tools\Desert.jpg";
        newMessage.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("Desert.jpg", file);
        newMessage.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;

        //this is required to fix the issue - Add content id programatically
        newMessage.Attachments[0].ContentId = "<Desert.jpg>";

        newMessage.Save();
```